Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n}$
Please help me find the limit of a sequence. I have tried all known methods, but I have not come to the desired result...
$$\begin{align*}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n}&=\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - \sqrt{n^3}}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n} \\[4pt]
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n\right)}{\left(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n\right)} \\[4pt]
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} {\left(\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n\right)} \\[6pt] &= \;\text{?}
\end{align*}$$
What should be done next ?
Sorry, I'm a new user... I'm not quite up to speed yet.

Hint: For any real $a > 0$, $(\sqrt{a + 1} - \sqrt{a})(\sqrt{a+1} + \sqrt{a}) = 1$.

To begin with, multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n$

$\sqrt{n^3+1}-n\sqrt n =\sqrt{n^3+1}-\sqrt{n^3}$.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

I showed my train of thought... but as it appears I came to a dead end because I received uncertainty.

You were on a right track. Do the same for the numerator and you get$$\frac{\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}+n}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}+n\sqrt{n}}\sim\frac{2n}{2n^{3/2}}.$$

First of all I rewrite the term of your limit as
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align*}\frac{\sqrt {n^3+1}-n\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}&= \frac{\cancel{n}\sqrt n \bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^3}}-1\bigg)}{\cancel n\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-1\bigg)}
\end{align*}$$
and for $n\to \infty$ we have the following relations using Taylor's series expansion
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^3}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2n^3} + o\bigg(\frac{1}{n^3}\bigg)\\
\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2n^2}+o\bigg(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)$$
and we got considering only the first term of T.S.E
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt {n^3+1}-n\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n} &=  \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt n \bigg( \cancel 1 + \frac{1}{2n^3}-\cancel 1+ o\bigg(\frac{1}{n^3}\bigg)\bigg)}{\bigg(\cancel 1 + \frac{1}{2n^2}-\cancel 1+ o\bigg(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)\bigg)}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} = \frac{\sqrt n \ n^2}{n^3} 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n }  = 0 
\end{align*}$$

Note: This method requires knowing T.S.E. so could be considered a step further what could be considered brute force calculation of the limit, but I think it's worth mentioning this as another possible approach. I hope this helps!

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n} \right)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - \sqrt{n^3}}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n} \right)=$$ $$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{(\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n)}{(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n)(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n)} \right) =$$ $$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( {(\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n)} \right)= $$ $$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{(\sqrt{n^3 + 1} - n\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n^3 + 1} + n\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n)}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1} + n\sqrt{n}} \right) =$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}+n\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n}{2\sqrt{n^3}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$$

Using the fundamental limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^k-1}x=k $ you have:
\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt{n^3+1}-n\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}= \frac{\sqrt n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^3}}-1\right)}{\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}-1}=\frac{\sqrt n}n\, \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^3}}-1}{\frac1{n^3}}\frac{\frac1{n^2}}{\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}-1}\to0\cdot\frac12\cdot2\end{align}
